# Retrieving class from getTag

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have set  `convertView.setTag(cell);` in my ListView adapter, which contains the ListCell class. I am trying to retrieve ListCell class with `getTag` whenever I click on one of the Listview items.

How would I go about using getTag in this situation where I would need to retrieve an entire class?

Activity - OnItemClick

```
this.GetAllCommentsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                //How would I retrieve the class here with getTag?

                Dialogbox();
            }
    });
```

Class

```
private class ListCell {
    private TextView comment;
    private ImageView PostImage;
    private TextView PostTitle;
    private TextView submitdate;
    private int commentID;
    private TextView PostVotes;
    private TextView commentCount;
    private int CurrentVote = -1;
    private ImageView PostUpvote;
    private ImageView userIconBackground;
    private ImageView userIcon;
    private GradientDrawable backgroundGradient;
    private int backgroundColor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final Object tag = v.getTag();
if(null != tag && tag instanceOf YourClass){
YourClass instance = (YourClass)tag;
}
```

Also you can use:

```
viewInstance.setTag(viewInstance.getId(), yourTagObject);
```

and then get tag by id if your view element.

Comment: What if the element doesn't have a view. Such as a integer ? How would I retrieve something in that case.

Comment: what element? all visible elements are view elements in android. also integer? instanceOf Integer - returns true if class is integer

Comment: same issue that I was having before. Its not letting me cast the tag to a ListCell

Comment: Could the casting be failing because inside my adapter my ListCell is listed as final?

Comment: I figured out the issue, your solution was correct however I was getting the  tag in the wrong class. I was calling it outside of the adapter. Instead i put an onitemclick inside the adapter and it seems to work.

Comment: No `final` makes no diffrence. Casting just tells, "hey, object XXX is of class YYY.  Trust me". If it cannot be casted (just because of class hierarchy, not qualifiers like `final`) you will get casting exception. So if that solves your problem, please approve the answer

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Thanks, I thought that I had approved already.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you just looking for ordinary casting:

```
ListCell lc = (ListCell)arg1.getTag();   // where arg1 is your View quoted method
```

Comment: Tried that and it says it cannot be casted to ListCell

Comment: Other than casting it to ListCell, would there be a way for me to cast only a single variable instead of the entire class?